# canvas update in running process

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

```
master = Tk()

canvas_width = 100
canvas_height = 250
w = Canvas(master, 
           width=canvas_width,
           height=canvas_height)
w.pack()

class Tetriminos(object):

    def __init__(self, position, pivot, color):
        self.position = position
        self.pivot = pivot
        self.color = color

    def left_shift(self):
        backup = copy.copy(self.position) 
        for i in range(len(self.position)):
            change = str(int(self.position[i][0]) - 1) + self.position[i][1:]
            if "-" in change:
                self.position = backup
                return False
            for j in self.position:
                if "0" in self.position:
                    self.position = backup
                    return False
            self.position[i] = change
        self.pivot[0] -=1

    def right_shift(self):
        backup = copy.copy(self.position)
        for i in range(len(self.position)):
            change = str(int(self.position[i][0]) + 1) + self.position[i][1:]
            if "0" in change:
                self.position = backup
                return False
            self.position[i] = change
        self.pivot[0] += 1

    def rotate(self): #direction?
        for i in range(len(self.position)):
            a = int(self.position[i][0]) - self.pivot[0]
            b = int(self.position[i][1:]) - self.pivot[1]
            a, b = a*0 + b*(-1), a*1 + b*0
            a += self.pivot[0]
            b += self.pivot[1]
            if a >= 0 and b >= 0:
                self.position[i] = str(a) + str(b)
            else:
                pass

    def drop(self):
        pass

    def slow_drop(self):
        for i in range(len(self.position)):
            change = self.position[i][0] + str(int(self.position[i][1:]) + 1)
            if int(change[1:]) < 26: #and no other tetrimino is in the way...
                self.position[i] = change
            else:
                return False
        self.pivot[1] += 1

    def draw(self):
        for i in range(len(self.position)):
            a = int(self.position[i][0])*10
            b = (int(self.position[i][1:])-1)*10 #Das Koordinatensystem ist gedreht!!
            c = (int(self.position[i][0])+1)*10
            d = (int(self.position[i][1:]))*10

            w.create_rectangle(a, b, c, d, fill=self.color)
            w.create_rectangle(a, b, c, d, fill=self.color)
            w.create_rectangle(a, b, c, d, fill=self.color)
            w.create_rectangle(a, b, c, d, fill=self.color)


tetrimino1 = Tetriminos(["302", "402", "502", "602"], [4, 2], "green")

tetrimino2 = Tetriminos(["402", "502", "401", "501"], [5, 1], "grey")

tetrimino3 = Tetriminos(["302", "402", "502", "401"], [4.5, 1.5], "yellow")

tetrimino4 = Tetriminos(["302", "402", "502", "301"], [4.5, 1.5], "blue")

tetrimino5 = Tetriminos(["302", "402", "502", "501"], [4.5, 1.5], "red")

tetrimino6 = Tetriminos(["302", "402", "401", "501"], [4, 1], "white")

tetrimino7 = Tetriminos(["402", "502", "301", "401"], [5, 1], "orange")

tetrimino_list = [tetrimino1, tetrimino2, tetrimino3, tetrimino4,tetrimino5,
              tetrimino6, tetrimino7]

settled_tetriminos = []

def draw():
    w.delete(ALL)
    current.draw()
    for t in settled_tetriminos:
        t.draw
        w.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    current.slow_drop()
    print(current.position)
    if int(current.position[1][1:]) == 25:
        w.delete(ALL)
        current.draw()
        w.update_idletasks()
        settled_tetriminos.append(current)
        return False
    w.delete(ALL)
    current.draw()
    for t in settled_tetriminos:
        t.draw
    w.update_idletasks() 
    w.after(100, draw)

current = random.choice(tetrimino_list)
draw()

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.button = Button(frame, 
                         text="Left", fg="red",
                         command=self.left())
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.button2 = Button(frame,
                         text="Right", fg="red",
                         command=self.right())
        self.button2.pack(side=RIGHT)
    def left(self):
        print("dsdsd")
        current.left_shift()
        current.draw()
    def right(self):
        print("ffff")
        current.right_shift()
        current.draw()

mainloop()
```

Okay, it kind of works now. But only for one piece. if I use any while-loop or recursive function, it doesn't as you said. But how could I avoid loops, if I want to get new tetriminos every time, the recent one is settled? If I use recursion, otherwise, it works internally, but doesn't show up on the canvas.

Or maybe you can tell me why this button doesn't work. it just performs the two methods once automatically and then I can't interact anymore. the buttons are dead.
Do you think its possible to program tetris this way, or do I need to change something radically?

Comment: You're not calling `update_idletasks`:  you need `w.update_idletasks()` -- Not sure if that'll fix it though.

Comment: `update_idletasks` doesn't specifically update the canvas; rather, it runs any "idle" tasks. Screen repaints are considered an idle task.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for certain what's going on, because the code you posted is missing some important bits of code.

That being said, however, the logic looks very screwy. For example, `drawdraw` has an infinite loop which you should never have in a GUI. `drawdraw` calls `draw`, and `draw` calls `drawdraw`, which means it's possible to be running an infinite loop inside an infinite loop.

It seems likely that you've set up a situation where the system never gets a chance to draw itself.

The best solution is to remove your infinite loop, and remove the recursion. Neither of those are necessary to do animation in Tkinter.

Comment: @BörjeSchweizer: your code seems to work for me -- all the pieces are dropping. However, all of the Tetriminos are on top of each other so you only see the top-most one. Also, you do have at least one other bug -- you have a line that says `t.draw` and it should be `t.draw()`. Finally, you can safely remove all calls to `update_idletasks`, they are completely unnecessary.